# iMac first time install failing after "try installing" selected from GRUB screen - black screen seen with white underscore

Tags: boot, mac

I have an old mac that I am converting to Ubuntu after having success with this in the past.

I have created a bootable USB drive, formatted to GPT and applied the Ubuntu ARM image (latest LTS version).

When the Mac boots, I am able to select the EFI drive, which takes me to the Ubuntu selection options.  When I click Try Install, the iMac freezes.

What I find strange is that I tried Xubuntu and managed to use this as a "try" option last week, then I installed ChromeOS to test, but since installing ChromeOS, I can't seem to get Xubuntu or Ubuntu to get past the Install selection on the boot screen.

Comment: Please be specific with details; what do you consider the *latest LTS* and are you talking about Desktop? Server? as fewer install options were available on *arm64* (with some only available for QA-testing and often include (*proposed*) packages not on released systems as they are *unsupported* products)

Comment: What specific model/year Mac do you have? How much memory is installed?

Comment: For a ARM Mac, use Asahi Linux https://asahilinux.org/. For Intel Mac, use the regular AMD64 version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Old iMacs (2006-2020) are Intel processor based, not ARM processor based. Very old original iMacs (1998-2005) are PowerPC processor based.